# How to get the value of variable assigned in $.ajax() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Here is my code. I want to get the "flag", but the "flag" is always "false". Even program executes to "flag=true", the "flag" becomes "false" when it's returned. How can I get the real value from $.ajax()? Please help me. Thanks

```
function checkUserName() {
var name = document.getElementById("userName").value;
var namemsg = document.getElementById("userNameMsg");
var flag=false;
if (name == "") {
    flag=false;
} else {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/vclub/verify/checkUserName.do",
        dataType : "json",
        data : "userName=" + name,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
                flag=true;
            } else {
                flag=false;
            }
        }
    });
}
alert(flag);
return flag;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Since AJAX is asynchronous, you need to use a callback. At the moment you receive the AJAX response after you return flag at the end of your code. The key point is that `success` is not called before `return flag`, since the anonymous function attached to `success` is called only when the response is received from the `url`. Note that since you may or may not run an AJAX request, you still need to use a callback function when you can provide the return instantly (if the name is an empty string). In this case, the callback will be executed shortly after flag is set to false. Otherwise, the checkUserName will likely complete before the AJAX returns.

```
function checkUserName(callback) {
    var name = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var namemsg = document.getElementById("userNameMsg");
    var flag=false;
    if (name == "") {
        // Note a callback is needed even if we don't use AJAX (because we might)
        flag=false;
        callback(flag);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/vclub/verify/checkUserName.do",
            dataType : "json",
            data : "userName=" + name,
            success : function(data) {
                if (data == true) {
                    flag=true;
                } else {
                    flag=false;
                }
                callback(flag);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
checkUserName(function (flag) {
    // Here, the flag variable is available, but will not run until "callback" is called above
    alert(flag);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answered. I have solved by adding "async : false," in $.ajax().

Comment: also be sure to mark the answer as the correct one in the future, otherwise people may be reluctant to answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

The `flag`'s value will change when the AJAX request finishes successfully, because the function that you assigned to `success` attribute of `$.ajax` function is a callback.
In fact your `alert(flag);` line of code will run before execution of `success` callback (When `flag`'s value is not changed yet).

If you move `alert(flag);` to the `success` callback, you will see it's value is changed.

I think you need to move `callback();` line to the function too.

Answer (score 0):

put the `async:false`,

```
function loadProcess(processId) {
    var prc;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '/processes/getprocess',
        data: {
            'id': processId
        },
        success(result) {
            prc = result;
        },
        error(xhr) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
    });
    return prc;
}
```